# Pass-though hardware interfaces to a separate device/computer

Tags: networking

Hypothetical: I have 2 computers in the same network with a high speed (10Gbps), low latency (0.6 - 0.7ms) ethernet connection, Say one of these computers has a BlueTooth interface or USB device (This computer is the **master**) and I want these devices to be 'passed through' to the other computer (The **slave**). Can this be done?

For simplicities sake let's say they are both running the same OS with a similar CPU (Same instruction set and are both 64 bit).

I'm imagining that you could pass the raw hardware instructions of an interface on the slave through ethernet on a certain port and set up the master to see this as a native hardware device. However, I have no idea if this is possible or where to start on something like this.

For those that may not understand what I mean in this situation, you could also compare it to a native passthrough of devices for a virtual machine from the VM host, except instead of a virtual machine, it is a different computer.

If anyone has a clear cut answer to this, please could you also elaborate on the possibilities of this sort of setup with computers of different hardware and different operating systems.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with standard operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For USB, you can use [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/). It's already present in the Linux kernel, and basically all distros should have packages for the tools.

For the server (the computer sharing the USB devices), you are restricted to Linux. Clients exist both for Linux and Windows.

Your "slave" is the server, your "master" is the client.

I do not know if there is something similar for Bluetooth. From my experience with the Bluetooth stack on Linux, I'd consider it unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I've fixed the master and slave placeholders. Seems counterintuitive to be the reverse, or at least in this instance, since all of these devices with usbs are being a 'slave' to the server.

Are there any other programs like usbip that can be applied to other sorts of devices like for instance pcie devices, maybe even ram (However stupid that would be in regards to latency) and cpu's?

I know for CPU's there is something called MPICH (Message passing interface communication protocol), commonly used in server farms for parallel computing.

Comment: Also, if you know the specific category name for these sort of features, sharing it would greatly help my search as currently, my searches are a mixed bag of results - almost none of which are the sort of results I'm looking for, and I have a strong feeling this because I do not know the correct terminology for this category.

Comment: Oops, as it turns out, you're very right about the master/slave usage, I'm just using the device sharing in a way backwards from how you would normally use it from server having all the devices and client receiving them all, lol my bad.